# How to do diffrent type of number rounding?

Tags: vb.net, rounding

[image: rounding type]

```
Dim dec as Decimal = 0.01
Math.Round(dec, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Above example can do Type 6 rounding how about other type? Especially Type 1.

*~ means 'To', example 0.01~0.03 means 0.01,0.02 and 0.03.

Comment: What is `~` used for here?

Comment: What kind of rounding is Type 1? I guess you'll need to do that by yourself

Comment: @rory.ap Example Type 8 0.01~0.06 means 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06 will round down to 0 and 0.07,0.08,0.09 will round up to 0.10

Comment: @vbnewbie -- Oh okay, that wasn't clear.  You may want to clarify that in your question, because that's not what `~` is typically used for, to indicate a range of numbers.  I would suggest using the word "to" instead.  It looks like some kind of formula that you want to work in code.  Same goes for the vertical bar `|`.

Comment: @Pikoh so that is no way to round up to 0.05 by using existing function? unless do by my own self?

Comment: For Type one (round to the nearest 0.05 i guess) try this `Math.Round(dec / 0.05, 0) * 0.05`

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to create your own class that'll take the Type as a parameter. Unless there's a 3rd party class somewhere that already does it.

Comment: Some of those dont look like any sort of rounding operation at all.  `.06 to .07` rounding to `.05` for instance.  More like a Math Floor/Ceiling function

Comment: See my comment @Plutonix. I think that `.06 to .07` rounding to `.05` seems like a currency round to the nearest 0.05 decimal

Comment: Yes, hard to glean *what* is desired from the description "Type 1"

Comment: The terminology here is not rounding but grouping. One way or another, you will need to do the appropriate math for each type.